# PyGObject: Drag and Drop with ToolPalette

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I have been able to get drag and drop working from a Gtk.ToolPalette, but only when setting `Gtk.ToolButton.set_use_drag_window(True)`. However when clicking on a ToolButton to drag and drop it, it does not result in the button actually being visually clicked. I understand this is because `set_use_drag_window` causes all events (even button clicks) to be intercepted as a drag event.

The docs say that the easiest way to use drag and drop with Gtk.ToolPalette is to call `Gtk.ToolPalette.add_drag_dest()` with the desired drag source palette and the desired drag target widget. This is kind of the opposite of what I need based on the complexity of the GUI app, since I need to setup the ToolPalette and then add a callback to the drag source after the DrawingArea is created.

I have inherited from the `Gtk.TooPalette`, created a `Gtk.ToolItemGroup` for each section of the palette, and then I am creating the buttons:

```
def toolbox_button(self, action_name, stock_id):
    button = Gtk.ToolButton.new_from_stock(stock_id)
    button.action_name = action_name
    button.set_use_drag_window(True)

    # Enable Drag and Drop
    button.drag_source_set(
        Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK,
        self.DND_TARGETS,
        Gdk.DragAction.COPY | Gdk.DragAction.LINK,
    )
    button.drag_source_set_icon_stock(stock_id)
    button.connect("drag-data-get", self._button_drag_data_get)

    return button
```

On the DrawingArea I am then making it a drag dest:

```
    view.drag_dest_set(
        Gtk.DestDefaults.MOTION,
        DiagramPage.VIEW_DND_TARGETS,
        Gdk.DragAction.MOVE | Gdk.DragAction.COPY | Gdk.DragAction.LINK,
    )
```

Is there a way to get drag and drop to work with the ToolPalette while still allowing the buttons to work normally?

Answer (score 0):

My fellow contributor dug in to the GTK source code and figured out that the Gtk.ToggleToolButton actually has a child button which isn't currently documented. Drag and drop works if you set the drag source to this "inner button".

```
def toolbox_button(action_name, stock_id, label, shortcut):
    button = Gtk.ToggleToolButton.new()
    button.set_icon_name(stock_id)
    button.action_name = action_name
    if label:
        button.set_tooltip_text("%s (%s)" % (label, shortcut))

    # Enable Drag and Drop
    inner_button = button.get_children()[0]
    inner_button.drag_source_set(
        Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK | Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON3_MASK,
        self.DND_TARGETS,
        Gdk.DragAction.COPY | Gdk.DragAction.LINK,
    )
    inner_button.drag_source_set_icon_stock(stock_id)
    inner_button.connect(
        "drag-data-get", self._button_drag_data_get, action_name
    )

    return button
```